# Can not understand 'pMany' and 'pMany1' in the parser combinator

Tags: parsing, haskell, combinators

I am trying to understand the pMany and pMany1 functions in the parser combinator

```
newtype Parser s t = P([s] -> [(t, [s])])
pMany, pMany1 :: Parser s a → Parser s [a] 
pMany p =(:) <$> p <*> pMany p `opt` [] 
pMany1 p = (:) <$> p <*> pMany p
```

As I understand, pMany runs the parser as many times as possible and collects the final result in [a]. What I don't understand is how it keeps track of the results between each run. The applicative combination is context-free and should not remember the state in between. Is that correct?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tangentally these functions and more can be [derived via](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia) the state transformer: `newtype Parser s t = P ([s] -> [(t, [s])]) deriving (Functor, Applicative, Alternative, Monad, MonadPlus, MonadState [s]) via StateT [s] []`. This gives you `pMany = many` and `pMany1 = some`.

Comment: More instances like `MonadFail`, `MonadFix` are available, consult the ghci command [`:instances StateT [_] []`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:instances) after running `:set -XPartialTypeSignatures -Wno-partial-type-signatures` to list them.

Comment: Well, `f <*> x` has to remember the function returned from `f` in order to call it on the value returned from `x`, no? You can't vary the syntax with the `f`, but you can definitely vary the result.

Comment: Basically, the elements parsed so far are stored in the closure that is the `[s] -> [(t, [s])]` function.

Comment: Thank you all! I guess I understand now. I missed the definition of <*>, which is P p1 <*> P p2 = P (\input -> [(v1 v2, ss2) | (v1, ss1) <- p1 input, (v2, ss2) <- p2 ss1]). This will run the parser in sequence and accumulate the elements parsed so far. @Cactus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down;

```
pMany p = (:) <$> p <*> pMany p `opt` []
```

basically means

```
pMany p = (fmap (:) p <*> pMany p) `opt` []
```

This expression consists of two parts:

- Parse `fmap (:) p <*> pMany p`
- If above fails, be okay with empty list as result

The idea here is to try to parse "an element and try to parse more" or "don't parse anything" if the previous step didn't succeed. I assume the second part is understandable, let's focus on the first.

What we will need here is to understand how do the `fmap` and `<*>` work:

- `fmap` is pretty simple: it takes a function `a -> b`, a parser `Parser s a` and returns `Parser s b`. This allows us to explicitly manipulate the results of the parser without actually running it.
- `<*>` works exactly the same as `fmap` with a little difference that the function is itself a result of a parsing. In (subjectively) most sane implementation it:

  - Runs the left side parser (**consuming** input) that returns a function
  - Runs the right side parser (on the **remaining** input) that returns an argument
  - Combines the above into a single parser that returns function applied to mentioned argument

So what happens in this mysterious `fmap (:) p <*> pMany p`:

- First we parse some object of type `a` using parser `p`.
- Then, inside of the parsing context, we apply function `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` to it. So if we have parsed, let's say, an int `2137`, we now have `(:) 2137` which is the same as `\rest -> 2137:rest`. At this point we have parser of type `Parser s ([a] -> [a])`.
- Next step is to parse the right side of the `<*>` operator which is recursive call to `pMany`. We can read this as "proceed with the same algorithm". Effectively, we parse the rest of the elements. This yields (according to the type of `pMany`) `Parser s [a]`.
- Finally, we apply the previous result over the last one getting a parser that attaches the left element (parsed with `p`) to the following ones (parsed with `pMany p`). From the type of `<*>` we can infer that the resulting type will be `Parser s [a]` as expected.

This code is semantically equivalent to

```
pMany p = (do
    someElem <- p
    restElems <- pMany p
    return (someElem : restElems)
  ) `opt` []
```

---

`pMany1` does the same trick, but fails if it can't parse the first element. Note that it calls `pMany` after that which doesn't have this property. As a result we force it to parse at least one thing ("parse one and then parse any number").

Comment: Great answer. Now I completely understand. Thank you so much!